# Clan castle during attack

Tags: clash-of-clans

During a clan war, sometimes I can't use my full clan castle during an attack. It doesn't even show up in my line up during the attack. How can I use it during attacks.

Comment: Wait.. Are you confusing between your **Clan Castle** (CC) and your **Clan War Castle** (CWC)?

Answer (score 2):

If you have troops in you clan castle you should be able to deploy them. They have your clan's flag as icon during battle. If you are not able to deploy them it is possible you have been attacked and lost all your troops there. Possibly without noticing/realizing.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is a simpler issue than others think... if you have too many different KINDS of troops, you may have to scroll right on your troop attack bar to find all of your troops. Spells usually show up on the right and I have paniced myself when I couldn't find that one spell I really needed.

So... try scrolling right (or left) on your attack bar.